# git diff/log retrieve also merged commits

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

given the following schema where an hotfix (D) released into master is merged back into test branch we need to found a way , with a diff between test and master, to get (B), (C) and also (D3).

```
hotfix      /------------D
           /              \
master ---A----------------D2--------
             \              \
test          \----B----C----D3------
```

every git diff (bot 2/3 dots ) would always return B and C but not D3 so we ended with a git log sequence:

checkout test :

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only HEAD...$( git log --format=%H origin/master..HEAD | tail -1 )^ | sort -u -k1,1
```

the idea is to retrieve all the commit since the common anchestor ( B, C, D3 ) and retrieve each resource changed.
That's "seems" to work but we maybe there's a better way to accomplish our task.

This approach has quite drawbacks:

- we loose control over diff filters : we also need to remove from the retrieve any deleted resource
- every "reverted" resource will be retrieved even if unchanged

Is there a better solution?

---

Try to better explain the problem

Requirements : generate a deployment package with changed resource between master and test. Resources must be retrieved, packaged and installed into multiple environments.

T0 : git diff master...test retrieve every resource from C, B. Bundle with resources is then installed into ENV1

```
hotfix      
           
master ---A--------------
             \             
test          \----B----C
```

T2 : git diff master...test retrieve every resource from C, B but not D3. Bundle will not contains D3 resources and will not keep ENV1 updated.

```
hotfix      /------------D
           /              \
master ---A----------------D2--------
             \              \
test          \----B----C----D3------
```

The statement must retrieve the resources that are on test and not on master but also the resources that are merged back from master to keep ENV1 updated.
The only way to align ENV1 is from commit/event on test

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

*note* : your diagram has 3 commits named `D` ....

```
hotfix      /------------D1
           /              \
master ---A----------------D2--------
             \              \
test          \----B----C----D3------
```

As far as the range of commits goes : I think you are looking for `master..D3` :

```
git log [any options] master..D3
```

If you want to *list the files that were modified between `A` and `D3`* : `A` is the merge base between `C` and `D2` :

```
git merge-base C D2
# or, starting from D3 :
#  -  'C' is 'D3^'  (first parent of D3)
#  - 'D2' is 'D3^2' (second parent of D3)
git merge-base D3^ D3^2
```

You can use this to get the diff between `A` and `D3` :

```
git diff [options] $(git merge-base D3^ D3^2) D3
```

If you want to llist only modified files, you may use `--name-status` or `--name-only` in the `[options]`.

Comment: yep, fixed .. using git diff does not retrieve files committed with D3, those files are identical to master. Whe need to retrieve them

Comment: indeed, since `master` is already merged, the 3 dots notation didn't start from where I thought. Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks, I think I got the point of merge-base but how about make merge-base dynamic? Next step is to retrieve D3^ and D3^2.  If another commit succeded on test ( E ) and so on ... maybe alternate a direct commit and a merge back from master how does merge-base could be used?  The goal is to have a generic statement to use

Comment: Hi, I'm glad this answer helps, but I must say understanding your goals from your question was more guess work than understanding. Reading your comment, I honestly do not understand what's your intention or your use case. Please, take the time to write down in simpler statements what you need, and what you have tried, and ask a new question for that.

Comment: add some context to better explain ( hope ), thanks anyway :)